Remove selected libraries from the Pip Cache
I have a library in development using a private PyPi server that I am trying to test with other python modules without having to update the version number after making changes.
My development environment uses tox, pyproject.toml, and setuptools for build.
After making a change to the upstream library, I try to clear the old files from the cache using: .tox/py38/bin/pip cache remove my_lib. Pip responds with Files removed: 19. So far so good. I then rerun tox, but it fails with this error:
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.

UPDATE: My requirements are specified in setup.cfg with no hashes specified. There is no requirements file.
I have a few questions:

How do I clear a single library out of the pip cache, so that I can avoid this error when rebuilding? I don't want to clear my entire cache.
Is there any way to force Pip to pull changes even if hashes do not match?
Is there any way to force Pip to check hashes even if files already exists in the cache?


It is reading the hashes from the requirements file.  You need to update that file not the pip cache.

Where is the requirements file located?

I have no idea.  It is your project :D

How are you invoking tox? Does your requirements.txt file really specify file hashes? - The requirements.txt file is in the root source dir of the project.

That is - if there is any requirements.txt file.

there is no requirements.txt file. dependencies are in setup.cfg and no hashes are specified in it

python3 -m tox --override testenv.set_env=PIP_INDEX_URL=private_pypi_url

1. Clearing a specific library from the pip cache:
You can clear a specific package from the pip cache using the following command:
pip cache remove --no-cache-dir --project <package_name>
Replace <package_name> with the name of your library. This command removes the package from the cache without affecting other packages.
2. Forcing pip to pull changes even if hashes do not match:
Since your requirements are specified in setup.cfg without hashes, you should not encounter hash mismatches. However, if you face this issue, you can use the --no-binary option with pip to force it to install from source instead of using cached files:
pip install --no-binary <package_name> <package_name>
This command will force pip to download and install the package from the source, ignoring any cached files or hashes.
3.Forcing pip to check hashes even if files already exist in the cache:
If you want pip to always check hashes and download the package again if hashes don't match, you can use the --no-cache-dir option:
pip install --no-cache-dir <package_name>
This command will force pip to ignore the cache and download the package from the source, verifying the hashes in the process.
Additionally, you're developing a library and testing it with other Python modules, you might find the following tips helpful:

Use a virtual environment: Create a separate virtual environment for your development and testing purposes. This will help isolate your dependencies and prevent conflicts with other projects on your system.
Use pip install -e . or python setup.py develop: These commands will install your library in editable mode, allowing you to make changes
to the source code and have them reflected immediately without having
to reinstall the package.
Consider using a tool like tox or nox for testing: These tools can
help you create isolated testing environments and run tests against
multiple Python versions and configurations.

By following these suggestions, you should be able to clear your pip cache selectively, force pip to pull the latest changes, and manage your development and testing workflow more effectively.
